# Unable to save tensorflow model containing the DNNRegressor estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am a beginner in Machine Learning, and I've got a small doubt!

I have been working on a machine learning code, where I am using tensorflow for predictions of future values. Now, the code uses a dataset which implements One Hot Encoding initially, then the OHE columns are combined and the estimator function is created. For the estimator model, I have used DNN Regressor. There is no Keras used anywhere in the code.

```
model=tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[100,100,100],feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
                                activation_fn=tf.nn.relu )
```

Now, I tried using Pickle for saving. However, I get this error:

`AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'DNNRegressorV2.__init__.<locals>._model_fn'`

I tried the same using joblib, but I got the following issue:

`PicklingError: Can't pickle <function DNNRegressorV2.__init__.<locals>._model_fn at 0x00000175F1A0E948>: it's not found as tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn.DNNRegressorV2.__init__.<locals>._model_fn`

Following this, I tried this code

```
tf.keras.models.save_model( model, filepath, overwrite=True, 
                            include_optimizer=True, save_format=None,  signatures=None, options=None )
```

But I got the error:

`AttributeError: 'DNNRegressorV2' object has no attribute 'built'`

I have also tried other methods such as model.save(), model.to_json(), and also tried saving using API - none of them worked out.

Can someone help me out with the same?

Comment: Seems like you're looking for
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#export_saved_model

Comment: Thank you! But...How can I implement it?